# Firebase hosting with rewrite to function doesn't set session cookie

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, express-session

I'm using nodejs express app with express-session and firebase.

Firebase hosting configured to be redirected to Firebase functions.

I'm trying to store some data in the session. It works perfectly if I access the app via function url.

However, app doesn't store session cookie when I'm trying to access it via hosting url.

E.g.

```
http://localhost:5001/my-project/us-central1/app/ - this one sets cookie
```

and

```
http://localhost:5000/ - this one not.
```

My app session configuration is the following:

```
app.use(
    session({
        secret: appConfig.appSecret,
        name: '__session',
        cookie: {
            secure: false,
            httpOnly: false
        }
    })
);
```

How to force firebase hosting to set the cookie?

Comment: Hosting won't set cookies so you will probably have to server all routes you want to set cookies through functions.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the solution.

In order to set a **__session** cookie, you need to set header for the response with a session.

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private');
```

Comment: same with cookie ...you saved my day man , thanks for both question and answer :)

Comment: Do you know why this 'Cache-control' header is needed to successfully set cookie if app is relying on Firebase Hosting's rewrite rule?

Comment: I think it relates to caching mechanism and cdn features of Firebase hosting but not 100% confident.